# A harmonic's amplitude is greater than the fundamental one

Tags: matlab, audio

Im writing a MATLAB code to detect frequencies in piano recording.

I used a C scale audio file that i recorded using my keyboard (C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 A4 B4 C5)

When i simply perform an FFT (without breaking into windows) then the fundamental frequencies have a higher amplitude which is perfectly fine.

However to be more accurate i did the following steps
 1. Did a fast convolution of my audio signal with a Gaussian edge detection filter to obtain the envelope.
 2. Implemented a peak detecting algorithm to find the note onsets.
 3. Taking each Onset, i performed an FFT on each, so as to get the FFT of each note.
However, when i do this for the above mentioned audio file, i get wrong results, at times the harmonics have a higher amplitude than the 1st.

```
clear all;
clear max;
clc;

%% create 5s sample at 10kHz with tone from 1s to 2s
FS = 10000; % 10kHz
N=5*FS;
song =  randn(N,2)/10;
song(FS:2*FS,:)=10*repmat(sin(261*pi*2*(0:FS)/FS)',1,2)+song(FS:2*FS,:);

P = 2000;   
t=0:1/FS:(N-1)/FS;                  % define time period


song = sum(song,2);                        
song=abs(song);


%----------------------Finding the envelope of the signal-----------------%
% Gaussian Filter
x = linspace( -1, 1, P);                      % create a vector of P values between -1 and 1 inclusive
sigma = 0.335;                                % standard deviation used in Gaussian formula
myFilter = -x .* exp( -(x.^2)/(2*sigma.^2));  % compute first derivative, but leave constants out
myFilter = myFilter / sum( abs( myFilter ) ); % normalize


% fft convolution
myFilter = myFilter(:);                         % create a column vector
song(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;      %zero pad song
myFilter(length(song)) = 0;                     %zero pad myFilter
edges =ifft(fft(song).*fft(myFilter));

tedges=edges(P:N+P-1);                      % shift by P/2 so peaks line up w/ edges
tedges=tedges/max(abs(tedges));                 % normalize

%---------------------------Onset Detection-------------------------------%
% This section does the peak picking algorithm
max_col = maxtab(:,1);
peaks_det = max_col/FS;
No_of_peaks = length(peaks_det);

%---------------------------Performing FFT--------------------------------

    song_seg = song(max_col(1):max_col(2)-1);
    L = length(song_seg);    
    NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y

    seg_fft = fft(song_seg,NFFT);%/L;

    f = FS/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
    seg_fft2 = 2*abs(seg_fft(1:NFFT/2+1));
    L5 = length(song_seg);

    fmin = 60;
    fmax = 1000;
    region_of_interest = fmax>f & f>fmin;
    froi = f(region_of_interest);

    [p_max,loc] = max(seg_fft2(region_of_interest));

    % index into froi to find the frequency of the peaks
    p_max;


     f_p_max = froi(loc);

     [points, locatn] = findpeaks(seg_fft2(region_of_interest));        
     aboveMax = points > 0.4*p_max;

        if any(aboveMax)
            peak_points = points(aboveMax)
        f_peak = froi(locatn(aboveMax))

    end

 end
```

What am I doing wrong here??? Really REALLY in need of some help here......

[image]

It can be seen that the f0 of D4 hasn't been detected at all, while the f0 of C4 and E4 have less amplitudes compared to their harmonics

Comment: I have two remarks. 1) are you sure you are using fft correctly (look at the help of fftshift) because I believe your calculation of frequencies is wrong. 2) could you slim the code down to just the bare essentials and provide sample data so we can reproduce your trouble. Also provide what output you get and what you should.

Comment: Are you referring to the fft ive used to find the envelope??

Comment: no I was talking about how you plotted it. But I see you used the code from help. Can you condense the code much more - say remove all the peak detection just hardcode one note and remove all the plots so there is just the code left to produce the first line of your table.

Comment: One line looks fishy: `f = FS/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);` - are you sure these is the correct frequency space for a note?

Comment: I hope the code's condensed enough. Well yes. This is the code mentioned on MATLAB help..... :/

Comment: lets try it on a sample signal. I replaced the wavread in your code. So let's see.

Comment: and just look at one 'signal'...

Comment: ok - your frequency calculation seems good.

Comment: so I also do just see a peak at 521, and not at 261 as is created for the test signal... so I suppose somewhere in the maths must do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering abs(song) is fine for finding the envelope, but when it comes to finding the peaks you need to compute the fft the original signal (without the "abs").

To see the difference, try:

```
clear;
FS = 10000;
s=sin(261*pi*2*(0:FS)/FS);
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(length(s));
S1=fft(s,NFFT);
S2=fft(abs(s),NFFT);
f = FS/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
plot(f,abs(S1(1:NFFT/2+1))); % peak near 261
plot(f,abs(S2(1:NFFT/2+1))); % peak near 522
```

Comment: Thank you.. I see the difference. But something really weird happened. All the notes whose harmonics were greater are now having a bigger fundamental (perfect) but all those which earlier DID have a higher fundamental are now having a slightly bigger 2nd harmonic!!!!
Do you know why this is happening???

Answer (score 1):

Using the FFT, i found out the peak in the Frequency Domain. This may correspond to the fundamental note, if we are very lucky. Else, this may be the 1st harmonic generally.

I do not know whether the peak is at the fundamental or at the 1st harmonic.
My job is to find this out.

What i did was...

1. I have the "max_user_freq" variable that corresponds to the frequency at which the peak occurs in the FFT.
   Note: "Spectrum[]" is the magnitude spec variable.
2. I calculate the maximum of the spectrum[m] where m ranges from frequency 
   Note : frequencies must be scaled to m. In my case : m=freq*length(fraw)/22050;
3. Complete Code:

   f1=(max_freq/2)-0.05*max_freq;

   f1=round(f1);
   f2=(max_freq/2)+0.05*max_freq;
   f2=round(f2);
   m=[];
   spec_index_fund_note=m;
   spec_fund_max=spectrum(f1*length(fraw)/22050;

   for m=f1:f2
       spec_index_fund_note(m)=m*length(fraw)/22050;
       if(spectrum(spec_index_fund_note(m))>spec_fund_max)
           spec_fund_max=spectrum(spec_index_fund_note(m)); 
       end

   end

   if((spectrum(max_freq_index)-specval_fund_note)/spectrum(max_freq_index)>)
           display('1st Harmonic exceeds the fundamental, Retry');
   end

Answer (score 0):

I code in matlab and develop applications that are useful for a Musician. I myself am a musician. So, i know the music theory t hat runs my algorithms.
I developed and algorithm in matlab that tells u the exact scale in which u are playing the piano. Have a Look

[MATLAB MUSICIAN's BLOG](http://matlabmusician.blogspot.in/2014/05/key-detection-algorithm-for-piano.html)